# How to use a debugger like GDB or LLDB to debug a crate in Rust?

Tags: debugging, rust, gdb, lldb

I am writing a new crate. I wrote some tests for it and run the tests using `cargo test`. After that, some `test_xxx` executables are generated in the `target` folder. I have enabled the debug option in `Cargo.toml`. By running `gdb targets/test_xxx`, I can list and debug the code in the `test_xxx` executable. However, I could not step into the functions in the crate. There is no debug information. How can I build/link the crate to include its debug information?

Comment: It seems that Cargo includes debug information by default in the current crate, but not in dependencies. How can Cargo be made to do this?

Answer (score 14):

Your question is a bit fuzzy, so I'll describe what I did:

Create a new crate:

```
cargo new --lib so
cd so/
```

Add a small bit of code:

**src/lib.rs**

```
fn thing1(a: i32) -> i32 {
    a + 2
}

fn thing2(a: i32) -> i32 {
    a * a
}

pub fn do_a_thing(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    thing2(b) - thing1(a)
}
```

Created an **external** test; one that lives in `tests`. This matches your comment about `test_XXX`, as best I can guess:

**tests/alpha.rs**

```
#[test]
fn it_works() {
    assert_eq!(1, so::do_a_thing(1, 2))
}
```

Run the tests (output trimmed):

```
% cargo test

     Running target/debug/deps/alpha-b839f50a40d747a9

running 1 test
test it_works ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

Open it up in my debugger:

```
% lldb target/debug/alpha-b839f50a40d747a9
```

Set a **regular expression** breakpoint on a method in the crate and run it:

```
(lldb) br set -r 'do_a_thing'
Breakpoint 1: where = alpha-b839f50a40d747a9`so::do_a_thing::hd55d34fb5a87e372 + 14 at lib.rs:10:11, address = 0x0000000100001f9e
(lldb) r
Process 53895 launched: '/tmp/so/target/debug/alpha-b839f50a40d747a9' (x86_64)

running 1 test
Process 53895 stopped
* thread #2, name = 'it_works', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100001f9e alpha-b839f50a40d747a9`so::do_a_thing::hd55d34fb5a87e372(a=1, b=2) at lib.rs:10:11
   7    }
   8
   9    pub fn do_a_thing(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
-> 10       thing2(b) - thing1(a)
   11   }
Target 0: (alpha-b839f50a40d747a9) stopped.
(lldb) p b
(int) $0 = 2
(lldb) p a
(int) $1 = 1
(lldb) br set -r 'thing2'
Breakpoint 2: where = alpha-b839f50a40d747a9`so::thing2::hf3cb71248518a556 + 11 at lib.rs:6:4, address = 0x0000000100001f5b
(lldb) c
Process 53895 resuming
Process 53895 stopped
* thread #2, name = 'it_works', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100001f5b alpha-b839f50a40d747a9`so::thing2::hf3cb71248518a556(a=2) at lib.rs:6:4
   3    }
   4
   5    fn thing2(a: i32) -> i32 {
-> 6        a * a
   7    }
   8
   9    pub fn do_a_thing(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
Target 0: (alpha-b839f50a40d747a9) stopped.
(lldb) p a
(int) $2 = 2
```

This indicates that I was able to set breakpoints and debug in my crate.

## For dependent crates

I added this to my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
time = "0.1.0"
```

Along with this code:

**src/lib.rs**

```
pub fn do_another_thing() -> bool {
    time::precise_time_ns() % 2 == 0
}
```

And this test (still in the external test file):

**tests/alpha.rs**

```
#[test]
fn it_works2() {
    assert_eq!(true, so::do_another_thing())
}
```

Built and ran the tests as before, then opened it in the debugger as before:

```
(lldb) br set -r 'precise_time'
Breakpoint 1: where = alpha-25aace4e290c57ee`time::precise_time_ns::h21114d10b3e2c8e8 + 8 at lib.rs:161:4, address = 0x0000000100002278
(lldb) r
Process 54043 launched: '/tmp/so/target/debug/alpha-25aace4e290c57ee' (x86_64)

running 2 tests
test it_works ... Process 54043 stopped
* thread #2, name = 'it_works2', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100002278 alpha-25aace4e290c57ee`time::precise_time_ns::h21114d10b3e2c8e8 at lib.rs:161:4
   158   */
   159  #[inline]
   160  pub fn precise_time_ns() -> u64 {
-> 161      sys::get_precise_ns()
   162  }
   163
   164
```

## Why a regex breakpoint?

Function names are mangled and namespaced. Our functions are actually called `so::do_a_thing::hd55d34fb5a87e372` or `time::precise_time_ns::h21114d10b3e2c8e8`. Using a regex breakpoint selects those easily without thinking about the exact name.

You can also use LLDB's autocompletion

```
(lldb) b so::<TAB>
Available completions:
    so::do_a_thing::hfb57d28ba1650245
    so::do_another_thing::hace29914503d7a2f
    so::thing1::ha6f7818d54de28d4
    so::thing2::h2518577906df58fd

(lldb) b time::<TAB>
Available completions:
    time::precise_time_ns::h21114d10b3e2c8e8
    time::sys::inner::mac::get_precise_ns::h64c88ed88da4ac18
    time::sys::inner::mac::info::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::ha03be28d018f231b
    time::sys::inner::mac::info::h364c1a0ef2ef1f0c
```

## Using GDB instead of LLDB

You can also use GDB, but it looks like it may be a bit harder. After setting a breakpoint in the primary crate's code, I stepped in and saw the function name seem to be the mangled version. You can use that as a breakpoint though.

Note my regex breakpoint doesn't work as intended, and also note the line number of the real breakpoint:

```
(gdb) rbreak precise_time_ns
u64 _ZN4time15precise_time_nsE()();
static u64 _ZN4time15precise_time_ns18os_precise_time_nsE()();
Breakpoint 1 ('_ZN4time15precise_time_ns18os_precise_time_ns13closure.24322E') pending.
<function, no debug info> time::precise_time_ns::os_precise_time_ns::closure.24322;

(gdb) b _ZN4time15precise_time_nsE
Breakpoint 2 at 0x1000052a0: file lib.rs, line 172.

(gdb) r
Starting program: /private/tmp/so/target/alpha-e0c6f11f426d14d2

running 2 tests
test it_works ... ok
[Switching to process 49131 thread 0xd03]

Breakpoint 1, _ZN4time15precise_time_nsE () at lib.rs:172
172 pub fn precise_time_ns() -> u64 {
(gdb) list
167
168 /**
169  * Returns the current value of a high-resolution performance counter
170  * in nanoseconds since an unspecified epoch.
171  */
172 pub fn precise_time_ns() -> u64 {
173     return os_precise_time_ns();
174
175     #[cfg(windows)]
176     fn os_precise_time_ns() -> u64 {
```

## Debugger wrappers

There are two wrapper programs shipped with Rust: `rust-lldb` and `rust-gdb`. These are intended to increase the usefulness of each debugger. It's worth giving them a shot.

Comment: Thanks shepmaster. I was able to replicate what you did using `lldb` but not `gdb`, which seems to indicate that `gdb` can only access debug symbols from the first crate (setting a breakpoint at `alpha.rs:7` works fine in gdb).

Comment: @dhardy I've updated with an example of GDB. It is indeed uglier, but possible. It *could* be a Rust issue, as I'd want both debuggers to be similar ;-)

Comment: Sounds like GDB needs to be updated. Anyway, I think you've earned the bounty; thanks for the help!

Comment: Shepmaster, thanks for the detailed instructions. I investigated more and found my question was inaccurate. It doesn't happen to all methods in an external crate, but only the generic ones. I filed an issue. Please see the comments in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19228.

Comment: there's rust-gdb also, that should remove all the mangling and make gdb usable with rust

Answer (score 1):

After receiving an answer, I found that this doesn't happen to all methods in an external crate, but only generic ones. I filed [issue 19228](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19228) with the detailed steps.

This is what I am doing to debug the generic methods in the meantime:

1. Write the tests in the tests folder as usual. Run "cargo test" to check if it is successful.
2. If it fails, I move the test code into the crate lib.rs file and build a binary using "rustc -g src/lib.rs".
3. Use `gdb` to debug `lib`.