# How to set a breakpoint inside a dependency in Rust?

Tags: debugging, rust, lldb, debug-symbols

I'm debugging my Rust project with

```
rust-lldb target/debug/my_project
```

I can set up breakpoints directly inside my project and they're working fine, e.g.

```
b function_inside_my_crate
Breakpoint 1: (...)
```

What I can't do is set up breakpoint inside my dependency from crates.io, e.g.

```
b function_inside_dependency
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

How can I create a breakpoint inside a dependency?

Comment: Function names are mangled and namespaced. Use a regex breakpoint. See [How to debug a crate in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27032271/155423); [Unable to set a breakpoint on main while debugging a program compiled with Rust 1.10 with GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416394/155423)

Answer (score 1):

Shepmaster answered my question in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416867/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-inside-a-dependency-in-rust#comment106879153_60416867). The names are mangled and they aren't always accessible with simple name match. The function name may be only a part of the full name that debugger uses. The best way to bypass this problem is to use regex name matcher, e.g.

```
br set -r 'function_inside_dependency'
```